# Scraping with Selenium not showing all data (possible duplicate)

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

I was trying to make a simple code for scraping a dynamic website (a newbie with Selenium here). The data I intended to scrape is the product name and the price. I ran over the code and it worked, but only showed 10 entries, while there are 60 entries for each page. Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get('https://www.tokopedia.com/p/komputer-laptop/media-penyimpanan-data') # the link

product_name = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='span.css-1bjwylw')
product_price = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='span.css-o5uqvq')

list_product = []
list_price = []

for i in range(len(product_name)):
    list_product.append(product_name[i].text)

for j in range(len(product_price)):
    list_price.append(product_price[i].text)

driver.quit()

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['product', 'price'])
df['product'] = list_product
df['price'] = list_price
print(df)
```

I used the chromedriver installer instead of downloading the driver first and then locating it because I just thought it was just a simpler way. Also, I used Service instead of Options (many tutorial using Options) because I got some errors with it, and with Service it worked out fine. Oh, and I used PyCharm, if that just makes sense of something, maybe.

Any help or suggestions will be very much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me you need to scroll down to bottom of the page first for all 60 of data to be loaded. As website is dynamic and as you scroll below data gets loaded. You can use javascript script for scrolling via webdriver as follows:  `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")` add this below `driver.get()` and before `find_elements()`.

Don't forget to use sleep after `scroll` as it require time to get loaded.

Comment: I tried to add javascript scrollTo, and instead of sleep, I used implicitly_wait; both worked really fine. Thank you!

Comment: Fyi, I upvoted your answer but I don't have enough reputation yet so I couldn't - -"

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. If you think it's correct answer you can mark it as answer. Yeah you just need some kind of delay in-between for page to be loaded.

Comment: So I tried to make a csv out of the df I made, but it turned out there was an error like this : 'Length of values (75) does not match length of index (10)'
Then I tried to put the implicit wait on another line, and also tried explicit wait; both didn't really work out fine (sometimes worked, sometimes didn't). Read some posts that selenium's waits sometimes could be unstable.

Comment: So issue is regarding selenium wait right?